# What is relationship and difference between Docker Volume and Volume Container

Tags: docker

I'm learning Docker. But I'm a little bit confused with the conception between Volume and Volume Container.
What is the relationship between them? In which case should I use Volume or Volume Container?

Anyone can help to clarify it?

Answer (score 2):

Before 1.9, [data volume container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/) was the only way to create a volume, but that volume was invisible once the container was removed.

In an effort to make volumes more visible and first-class citizen, [PR 14242](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/14242) was introduced and you can now create/list volumes without having to create a container.